# Sidekiq "default" queue not running next job until first one completes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

For some reason, my sidekiq queue just contains two jobs. The first one takes awhile whereas the second one should only take about 10 seconds. When queueing up the second one, the second one never runs until the first one completes.

Is my `config/sidekiq.yml` file misconfigured perhaps? This is what it looks like:

```
development:  
  :concurrency: 50
production:  
  :concurrency: 50
:queues:
  - default
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails limits Sidekiq to concurrency: 1 in development mode so code reloading works and is threadsafe.

Comment: Is there any way to increase it in development mode?

Comment: Turn on eager loading. Code reloading is not threadsafe so they need a global mutex.